# How do I move the button after the character :

Tags: html

I have the following problem in html: Cannot move the add button to the side. I have tried inserting the words within the div of the button or removing the br/ in the button div. It doesnt work. I know this seems to be a stupid question to all the pros out here but im seriously stuck

```
<h4>More details: </h4>
<div class="col-md-1">
 <div class="form-group">
                                                        
  <div class="text-sm-center">
                                                        
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-rounded" id="addrow"><i class="dripicons-plus"></i></button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Where exactly do you want the button? To the left of the Module ID input field? Can you post more of your code including the element that holds the rest of the row?

Comment: Headings and divs are block-level elements. Unless you force things to be inline-block or use `display: flex` with a container nesting the `<h4>` and `<button>`  to align in row format (side-by-side), the button will always occupy the "next" line.

Comment: side of what???

Comment: @epascarello My guess is that the OP was referring to aligning the h4 and button horizontally, with the h4 on the left and the button on the right. Could be wrong, question wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the `<h4>More details:</h4>` element to be side-by-side with the `+` button in a row format. Since [`<h1>-<h6>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) and `<div>` tags are [block-level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) the only way to have your `h4` in the same row as the nested `<button>` is to manipulate the amount of space each element occupies, ie change their layout with CSS.

> A Block-level element occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent element (container), and vertical space equal to the height of its contents, thereby creating a "block".

To make the `<h4>` and the `+` button right next to eachother, you could use [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and nest your HTML in a parent container `<div class="row">`.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.row .btn {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <h4 class="details-heading">More details: </h4>
  <div class="col-md-1">
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="text-sm-center">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-rounded" id="addrow">&plus;<i class="dripicons-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can just use CSS. You need all three of the parent DIV elements to have zero px for `border-left`, `margin-left` and `padding-left`.

Try adding another class to each, like:

```
<h4>More details: </h4>
<div class="col-md-1 left-side">
 <div class="form-group left-side">
                                                        
  <div class="text-sm-center left-side">
                                                        
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-rounded" id="addrow"><i class="dripicons-plus"></i></button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.left-side {
  margin-left: 0px;
  border-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Some prefer `0` to `0px`.

The reason to use another class, i.e. `left-side` is to avoid messing with any other elements elsewhere of the existing classes.

This method/answer is a bit of a hack; more elegant solutions will be out there.